# How to convert case class RDD to RDD[String]?

Tags: scala, class, apache-spark, case, rdd

I am having one schema rdd. If I print that RDD, I will get the output like
caseclass_name(col a, col b,col c)
caseclass_name(col d,col e, col f)
.....
.....
I need to display simply as (without case class name in front)
col a, col b, col c
col d, col e, col f

How can I get this? Please assist

Comment: What's the type of the RDD? It seems like it's `RDD[(caseclass_name, caseclass_name)]`.  Can you confirm?

Comment: RDD[caseclass_name]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is to override the `toString` method in your case class

```scala
case class iclass(Id1:Int,Id2:Int,SaleDate:String,Code:String) {
  override def toString(): String = {
    s"$Id1,$Id2,$SaleDate,$Code"
  }
}
```

If you have an `RDD[iclass]` and want to convert it to an `RDD[String]`, you can then just map it like `insureRDD1.map(_.toString)`

Comment: In that case you wouldn't wouldn't do the `map(_.toString)`.  Instead you'd do `rdd.toDF`.  E.g `spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(iclass(7, 8, "2014-02-02", "AK"))).toDF`